# Prisma generate types without pushing changes to database

Tags: prisma

Is there any way to make Prisma to generate all the typescript types without connecting to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to run the `generate` command and it should generate the TS types for you.

According to the Prisma docs:

> The generate command generates assets like Prisma Client based on the generator and data model blocks defined in your prisma/schema.prisma file.

[Checkout the docs here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/command-reference#generate)

Try running this in your terminal:

```bash
npx prisma generate
```

or adding a script to your `package.json` like so:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "generate": "prisma generate"
  }
}
```

and calling it using your preferred package manager CLI:

```bash
# with npm
npm run generate

# with yarn
yarn generate

# with pnpm
pnpm generate
```

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: It turns out that you need to be connected to the database to run the command, which is not always the case for me. I was looking for a command to generate the types without the need to be connected to the database. Thanks

Comment: I just ran this command without a connection to my database by removing the connection string in my `.env` file and it worked fine. Maybe you have some additional generators in your Prisma schema that might require a db connection? if so, you can run the command with the `generator` filter to only run the client? `prisma generate --generator client`